# Why does my WPF TabControl automatically switch tab?

Tags: c#, wpf

In a `TabControl` with 3 tabs:

1. `Tab1` contains a "Next" button.
2. When "Next" is clicked `TabControl` is set to display `Tab2` and a timer starts (2 seconds)
3. After the timer ends `TabControl` is set to display `Tab3`.

If the window containing the `TabControl` does not have focus when #3 happens, it will switch back to display `Tab2` when it receives focus. Why?

`MainWindow` code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void NextBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DoStuff();
        }

        private async void DoStuff()
        {
            MainTabControl.SelectedItem = Tab2;

            await Task.Factory.StartNew((Action)(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }));

            MainTabControl.SelectedItem = Tab3;
        }
    }
}
```

WPF code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Topmost="True">
    <TabControl Name="MainTabControl">
        <TabItem Name="Tab1">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Tab 1" />
            </TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Tab 1 content" />
                <Button Name="NextBtn" Click="NextBtn_Click" Content="Next tab" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Name="Tab2">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Tab 2" />
            </TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Tab 2 content" />
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Name="Tab3">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Tab 3" />
            </TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Tab 3 content" />
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

Full project: https://ufile.io/165121

Comment: Maybe not directly related, but you are using `async void` as something other than event handler, that's a big anti-pattern.  `DoStuff` also looks more complicated than it needs to be. you can just `await Task.Delay(2000); MainTabControl.SelectedItem = Tab3;` instead of messing with threads.

Comment: `DoStuff()` is a dummy method (that reproduces the issue) for what's essentially "Click a button, initiate long-running background work, wait for work to finish, display result.". I'm not _actually_ calling `Thread.Sleep()` for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 4):

I debuged your program with Snoop and I saw that when you call to 
`MainTabControl.SelectedItem = Tab3;` and you had the focus in other window, the tab2 is **focused** so when you select the program's window, the tab2 is showed.

I fixed it adding the second line:

```
MainTabControl.SelectedItem = Tab3;
((TabItem) MainTabControl.SelectedItem).Focus();
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: It doesn't work when the tab change occurs while the Window is minimized - but better than never working ;)

Comment: This really helped me thanks. In my situation the tab I was switching to would launch a "helper window" when it was activated. The helper window stole focus before the tab control finished updating resulting in the behavior you described. I know this is old but for the minimized situation I'd probably monitor the window state and when the control becomes visible I'd ensure the currently selected tab is focused. But be aware that using focus can change what tab is displayed but seems to not update the selected tab property correctly, so ensure that the selected tab is what will be focused.